# free pointers without <stdlib.h>

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to know how to free a pointer without using any header file like `<stdlib.h>`.

I'm using a platform (VX RTOS) where I can't use `<stdlib.h>` so I get an error message saying `implicit declaration of function 'free' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]`.

I have several functions in my code containing pointers. And I'm calling them several times in my cold. So I believe I should free the pointers. I want to know how to free them. I've put one function from my code here.

```
int complex1(double a1,double b1,double c1,double d1,int op,double *e1, double *f1){
double c2d2;
    //a=real(complex no1);b=imag(complex no1);c=real(complex no2);d=imag(complex no2);c2d2=sqrt(c1*c1+d1*d1)
    /*op=type of operation
        op=1: addition
        op=2: substraction
        op=3: multiplication
        op=4: division  
        op=5: absolute value 
    */
    //Resultant compex number is in the form of e1+1j*f1
    //Comlex number addition
    if (op==1){
        *e1=a1+c1;
        *f1=b1+d1;
    } 
    //Comlex number substraction
    if (op==2){
        *e1=a1-c1;
        *f1=b1-d1;
    }   
    //Comlex number multiplication
    if (op==3){
        *e1=a1*c1-b1*d1;
        *f1=b1*c1+a1*d1;
    }   
    //Comlex number division
    if (op==4){
        c2d2=c1*c1+d1*d1;
        *e1=0;*f1=0;
        if (c2d2 != 0){
            *e1=(a1*c1+b1*d1)/(c2d2);
            *f1=(b1*c1-a1*d1)/(c2d2); 
        }
    }       
    //free(*e1);free(*f1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you cannot use `free`, you would also have to implement `malloc` yourself no? Are you on an embedded target?

Comment: Smells like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Per C standard you can only call free with pointers returned by malloc/realloc/calloc. So where do you obtain the pointer from if you don't have stdlib.h?

Comment: If you have the `*alloc()` functions but not the `free()` function, you're not working with a standards compliant C implementation in which case I highly suggest considering other hardware platforms as this will be the first of _many_ issues you face in the future.

Comment: Also if you only have a "implicit declaration" warning but no "undefined reference" error, then probably your C support library do have malloc/free but you just didn't get the header correctly. If that's the case, you can still use forward declaration to get around it, although it's still better to get stdlib.h included correctly.

Comment: You **don't free pointers** in C. You free objects obtained [as if] by `malloc`. The pointer argument to `free` needs to point to such an object and tells `free` what to free.

Comment: If your implementation doesn't provide a workable `<stdlib.h>`, is there any guarantee that you've got workable versions of _any_ of the functions normally declared in `<stdlib.h>`?  You should probably concentrate on getting `<stdlib.h>` fixed rather than anything else.

Comment: @Harshani How did you call malloc without including <stdlib.h>?

Comment: What is your development environment and platform ?

Comment: Ok, I'll try some guessing: could you happen to use FreeRTOS or some other OS, and use some custom memory allocation functions, possibly even **called** `malloc`? IIRC, there is one reference implementation for FreeRTOS which is `malloc`-only and does not allow to `free` memory. This is a typical situation, where you allocate blocks at startup, but then works on this semi-static memory.

Comment: The platform I'm using is VX RTOS

Comment: The edit does not make it any clearer. How was the block allocated? If there is a `malloc` there **has to be** a `free`. Otherwise you might not even be supposed to deallocate the object. Read the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't include the header file, but you're linking to a C standard library implementation, then you can simply declare the prototype and the warning will go away.

Declare the function `free(3)` at the top of your file

```
void free(void *ptr);
```

Comment: Still doesn't explain how they got any of the `*alloc()` function declarations though :P

Comment: The names in the standard library are reserved names (in a hosted environment). An application shall not declare them on its own.

Comment: @Olaf: No, see 7.1.4 Use of library functions, ¶2: *Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header.*

Comment: @R..: I mostly refered to 7.1.3: Bullet 4: "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage". And indeed `void free(...` has external linkage. Let alone it makes no sense: if there is no `malloc` etc., there is no `free`. Otherwise, there should be some other mechanism to release memory.

Comment: @Olaf: That means that you can't provide your own definitions or conflicting declarations, not that you can't make a declaration for the standard definitions, which was explicitly permitted above.

Comment: Well, you shall definitively not define functions with the same name as standard library functions, that's for sure. All assuming a hosted environment. Which I strongly doubt (see my last comment to the question). Too bad OP apparently lost interest in his question, I hate that. (call me old-fashioned, but I find it pretty unpolite.)

Comment: Ok, I accept that you **can** do this theoretically. But we still don't know **why he cannot include `stdlib.h`. Any hosted implementation is required to provide it (and `malloc`/`free` etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If for some dubious reason you cannot include `<stdlib.h>`, you can declare the  function `free` as this before using it:

```
void free(void *);
```

If your system does not have a symbol named `free` in its C library, you will get a link time error.  If it does, one can only hope that it is a conforming implementation of the standard `free()` function.

Comment: There's no guarantee that you'll get a link time error if the implementation has a non-conforming implementation of `free()`; you'll only get a link error if there's nothing called `free` to be linked to.  C++ has type-safe linkage; C does not.  There's also no guarantee you'll get a runtime error if there's a non-conforming implementation of `free()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you are absolutely correct, I shall rephrase my answer.

Comment: Well, you _could_ use `sbrk` or `brk`, as declared in `unistd.h` if you really can't use `stdlib.h`. But these only work on *nix IIRC.

Comment: @Olaf: You can't define your own, but you most certainly can *declare* them yourself as long as your declarations match the requirements of the standard and no typedefs from the header are needed for the declaration.

Comment: @c650: Are you aware of a Unix/POSIX system which does not provide `stdlib.h` with `free`?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how to free a pointer without using any header file like `<stdlib.h>`.

While you might be able to get away with declaring

```
void free(void* ptr);
```

I strongly recommend not taking that route, especially if you use Visual Studio.
Use `#include <stdlib.h>` unless you have a very strong reason not to.